# Responsive Images to the right and left of the Youtube (Iframe) in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

I had a case that I can not figure out how to solve.
I have a Bootstrap 3 section where the video is in the center.
I need to add one image to the left of the video edge, the second image to the right of the video edge. Just like I schemed in the picture.

I tried to do this with `position: absolute`; and everything was fine, but when the screen is scaling, problems occurs. How do I make the images look like they are on the image, but was everything okay with responsiveness?
[image]

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<section id="trailer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/170x400" alt="" class="trailer_wrapper--one img-responsive">
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/PGNiXGX2nLU"></iframe>
</div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/170x300" alt="" class="trailer_wrapper--two img-responsive">    
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by splitting `sm-12` to a *2+8+2*

```css
.pl-0 {
 padding-left: 0 !important;
}
.pr-0 {
 padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="trailer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-2 pr-0"> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/170x400" alt="" class="trailer_wrapper--one img-responsive"> </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 pl-0 pr-0">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/PGNiXGX2nLU"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 pl-0"> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/170x300" alt="" class="trailer_wrapper--two img-responsive"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Hi Since you are using bootstrap, please align your code with bootstrap grid system, 

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<style>
img{
    width:30px;height:30px;
}
.embed-responsive{
    width:100%;
}
</style>
<section id="trailer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-lg-2">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/170x400" alt="" class="trailer_wrapper--one img-responsive"/>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-xs-8 col-lg-8">
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/PGNiXGX2nLU"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-lg-2">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/170x300" alt="" class="trailer_wrapper--two img-responsive">  
    </div>
</div>

    </div>
</section>
</html>

You can style the height and width of image as per your need. This makes your website looks responsive and good looking.
Happy coding !! :)
```